# selecting a column of a matrix created from a list in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code which generates a 5 column x 7 row matrix

```
var flatMatrix = [1,1,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,2,0,4,4,0,0,0,5,5,0,1,0,2,2];
var m = 5;
var r = 3;

var numbers = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(flatMatrix).enter().append("text")
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return (i % m)*50 + 10 + r; })
    .attr("y",function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i / m) *50+50; })
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("mouseover",function(d) { d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1.0); })
    .on("mouseout",function(d) { d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.5); })

var columns = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(flatMatrix).select(function(d, i) {return i % m});
console.log(columns);
```

I am now trying to group together columns to perform actions on them such as an opacity transition:

```
columns.transition().style("opacity", 1).duration(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways for doing this. I personally would create an array of objects based on `flatMatrix`, with each object having three properties: `column`, `row` and `value` (check my [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432941/selecting-a-column-of-a-matrix-created-from-a-list-in-d3#comment73925148_43433120)), so you can easily manipulate your data later on.

Nevertheless, this is possible with that flat array you have. However, you should use `selection.filter` instead.

For instance, making the third column (i == 2) red:

```
var columns = numbers.filter(function(d, i){
    return i % m === 2;
}).attr("fill", "red");
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var flatMatrix = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2];
var m = 5;
var r = 3;

var numbers = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(flatMatrix).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return (i % m) * 50 + 10 + r;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return Math.floor(i / m) * 50 + 50;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var columns = numbers.filter(function(d, i) {
  return i % m === 2
}).attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Any chance you could also show me the array of objects approach too? It will probably be what I need as I create more complicated subselections of the matrix with animation/interactivity

Comment: Here is an example, each object has a `column`, `row` and `value` property: https://jsfiddle.net/bqtLfey2/